# Python PYQT QLineEdit font color

Tags: python, pyqt

How can  I change the font color in `QLineEdit`?

```
self.texteditor1= QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
font = self.texteditor1.font()     
font.setPointSize(10)              
self.texteditor1.setFont(font) 
self.texteditor1.setFixedWidth(640)
self.texteditor1.setFixedHeight(30)
self.texteditor1.adjustSize()
self.texteditor1.move(20,120)
```

Comment: Have you googled the methods available? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I am new to python. I have tried to google but couldn't find. Would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Everyone would love it if someone else would do work for them. That's not what this site is for. It's for people to put in a reasonable effort to solve their own problems and then when stuck, provide a clear question that shows effort so others can help. You haven't done that yet.

Comment: I've reduced the indentation in your code, but you need to say what **problems** you have with the code you have posted as we don't know what you need.

Comment: I want to specify text color in QLineEdit